# Where are default rights definied in Sitefinity 3.6?

Tags: sitefinity

In a fresh install of 3.6 I see the following types of rights available to set for roles:

- Manage users
- Manage permissions
- Manage files
- Edit templates
- CmsAccess

As we will be doing some custom development which is likely to need similar security, I want to understand the implementation of these roles.

I can see that roles are mapped to specific permissions in the sf_SecPerms table.  But after plenty of poking around I haven't been able to find where those 5 rights are defined. Is it baked into a DLL?  Is it in the database?  Is it in config?

Comment: disclosure:  I did post the same question to the sitefinity forums.  Not trying to betray SO; just looking for help to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct these are baked into a dll if you use Reflector you can find them in the Telerik.Cms.dll

They are in the namespace Telerik.Cms.Security there is an Enum called GlobalRights.

Another class to take note of in the same Namespace is the GlobalPermission class which is used to query and set these permissions.